# MySQL - Does ROUND() make use of indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing, rounding

Does MySQL make use of any indexes when using the `ROUND()` function?

Consider this query:

```
SELECT CPRID,ROUND(Dist*1000) AS `Distance` 
FROM CPRaw_ID1 
GROUP BY ROUND(1000*Dist) 
ORDER BY ROUND(Dist*1000)
```

Will MySQL Still use my Index on the `Dist` column?

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN` at the start of the query to see if it's using any indexes.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with your query?

Comment: Ah, the query is only for demonstration.. i am just considering changing from a Float to a Int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see whether index on Dist will be used in the query. I did an experiment and found out that is not.

Actually, an sugguestion is [avoid using functions in where clause](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/17/mysql-performance-eliminating-order-by-function/). Also, this explained [how mysql uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization-indexes.html).

In the query you post, I think you can try to create another table and put the result of the query:

```
SELECT CPRID,ROUND(Dist*1000) AS `Distance` 
FROM CPRaw_ID1
```

into that temporary table and build index on Distance. Then the index will be used to accelerate the query.

Answer (score 0):

if your storing the values in kilometres and you want to convert it to metres I think this query would be enough:

```
SELECT CPRID, ROUND(Dist*1000, 2) AS `Distance` 
FROM CPRaw_ID1 
GROUP BY Dist
ORDER BY Dist
```

in this manner you would able to use the index if you define the index for the Dist. The second parameter on the ROUND function will identify the decimal places you need if you set it to 0 there will be no decimal and it will automatically round the value.

Comment: Your query will raise an error, and the answer is not the answer to the question of the OP.

Answer (score -3):

no it won't and you do have a bad query too.

Comment: Please explain why the query is bad.

Comment: actually the problem is existing in your "group by" statement in your query I don't see any reasons why you still need to multiply each value by 1000 to which you could directly do it by just using "Group By Dist", I believe that would make the same thing. In your query above it means that every time the database encounters a different value he'll first multiply them by 1000 before proceeding on grouping the values if you have few data on your db you won't observe how it may affect it's performance the goal of the db is to provide the answers for each query in the fastest possible time...

Comment: ... on your query it may seem to impede that goal also on your comment above you said that you want to convert the values from Float to integer then why not do it like this "ROUND(Dist, 0)" that will instantly round the the values and on the statement above even if you multiply it by 1000 which is an integer it will still be converted back to float again because your multiplying an int and float at the same time.

Comment: and another thing why I said it won't use your index for the Dist column it's simply because in your query there is still process for evaluation so for any reason it would be a different value by then and is not part of the index anymore in some case let us say that the database will use the index but it will be useless now because of the process that occurs before the group by performs its work it's expensive in the processing time. Please take note "Round" is a function and has a process inside it. I hope that make sense. :)

Comment: and before you use a function manually validate the result from what you expect "ROUND(Dist*1000)" I think this will return a wrong result for you it may just remove the decimal point on your value for example 49.505 it will turn into 49505 is this really your goal?

Comment: yes it is, here i am converting kilometres to metres. I am actually going to store metres in the database (the integer) which will make several things easier/faster